# Google Geochart dynamic values from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-docs

This is a little out of my ability and I think I'm just missing a small detail. I am trying to get a heat map (Google geochart) of the US to update dynamically based on numbers from a Google Spreadsheet.

I have a working example

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
    <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
          function drawRegionsMap() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['State', 'Pledge'],
              ['Wyoming', 5],
              ['Alasak', 10],
              ['Arizona', 15],
              ['Nevada', 20],
              ['Colorado', 25],
              ['Algeria', 7],
              ['Algeria', 17],
              ['Idaho', 27],
              ['Algeria', 13],
              ['Montana', 3],
              ['Utah', 33],
              ['California', 30],
              ['Oregon', 27],
              ['Washington', 13],
              ['New Mexico', 10],
              ['Texas', 13],
              ['Kansas', 10]
            ]);

    var options = {
        region: 'US',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
        colorAxis: {
          colors: ['#444444', '#f70000']
        },
        backgroundColor: '#222222',
        datalessRegionColor: '#333333',
        defaultColor: '#333333',
        legend: 'none'
      };
            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          };
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/75L98227/

But when I try and switch the source of the geochart to be pulling from a Google Doc nothing pops up, as seen here

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['geochart']}]}"></script>
    <div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

          function drawRegionsMap() {
            var query = google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FxR8f6JujykDpNW1HOZPQoGV3h73e42dpfDCVvOlXdY&sheet=ByState&range=A1:B51&headers=1');

            query.setQuery('select A,B');
            query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
            function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
                    if (response.isError()) {
                        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }

            var options = {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#444444', '#f70000']
              },
              backgroundColor: '#222222',
              datalessRegionColor: '#333333',
              defaultColor: '#333333',
              legend: 'none'
            };

            var data = response.getDataTable();
            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          };
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x5rykyhj/

I don't know what I'm missing. This is what I've based anything I've built so far off of: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several issues -- the Query was incorrect in that the gid needs to be set to get to sheet 2 and you did not use the "new" keyword. NOTE on the gid, navigate to the spreadsheet online and select the sheet you want, use the URL and do not try to use the sheet query selector. It does not work.

I did this before, sample page is here:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/GoogleCharts.GoogleChartSamples.Development.USPopulation

Here is a fiddle that I created from yours (I added a table to see what data was being retrieved to be sure):

http://jsfiddle.net/x5rykyhj/4/

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FxR8f6JujykDpNW1HOZPQoGV3h73e42dpfDCVvOlXdY/edit?gid=143931468&headers=1&range=A1:B51');
    //query.setQuery('select A,B');
    query.send(handleQueryResponseTR);
    }
    function handleQueryResponseTR(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' +            response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

    var options = {
      region: 'US',
      displayMode: 'regions',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      colorAxis: {
        colors: ['#444444', '#f70000']
      },
      backgroundColor: '#222222',
      datalessRegionColor: '#333333',
      defaultColor: '#333333',
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
        table.draw(data, {
    width: '100%', height: '100%'
});
  };
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you are a wizard.